# Law of Demeter confusion in Java

Tags: java, law-of-demeter

Am I breaking the “Law of Demeter”?
For example i create a Class person which contains name, phone and id and it match the column in my database.
When I want to fill my Order info using person's id.I do like this.

```
 public static void fill(Order order) {
    DatabaseComponent databaseComponent = new DatabaseComponent();
    Person person = databaseComponent.getById(order.getUserId());
    order.setName(person.getName());
    order.setPhone(person.getPhone());
}
```

I use getName and getPhone return by databaseComponent.That's break LoD.
Somebody recommend that I can do like this

```
 public void fill(Order order) {
    DatabaseComponent databaseComponent = new DatabaseComponent();
    Person person = databaseComponent.getById(order.getId());
    fillOrder(order,person);

}
private void fillOrder(Order order,Person person){
    order.setPhone(person.getPhone());
    order.setName(person.getName());
    return;
}
```

But I think in public method it still break the LoD.Some people use this method.

```
public class Util {
public static void fillOrder(Order order,Person person){
    order.setPhone(person.getPhone());
    order.setName(person.getName());
    return;
}}
```

Yeah Maybe it doesn't break LoD. But why?May be Client isn't coupled to the class Person.But it is coupled to Util. What are the advantages of LoD  on this occasion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LoD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) says:

> More formally, the Law of Demeter for functions requires that a method m of an object O may only invoke the methods of the following kinds of objects:[2]
>
> O itself
>
> m's parameters
>
> Any objects created/instantiated within m
>
> O's direct component objects
>
> A global variable, accessible by O, in the scope of m

You are creating objects in your method (order and person); and then you call methods on them. Or to be precise: you are *creating* one and *instantiating* another one.

Seems fine to me - no violation of LoD here.

I would rather be worried about *tell don't ask* here. You fetch all these properties of a Person to push that into an Order. Why not have a method on the order class like `public void setRecipient(Person p)` or something alike?

On the other hand, that could mean to break the single responsibility of Order. In that sense your code could still be ok, for example if to be found within some `SetupOrderService` support class.

Comment: Object person is create by MyBatis. You means that it equals to that I create a person object in my method? I'm not sure.

Comment: Read carefully - it says "create or instantiate". But I updated my answer to be more clear here.

Comment: What's more? I hava a class named A which have 4 fields. field1 to field 4.Then  in my code ,i use them like this, if (souce == 1) A.setField1(value) else (source == 2) a.setField2(value) else if(source == 3) A.setField3(value) else A.setFeild4(value).

Comment: Then i want to move it into Class A.Then there is a method in a.public void setField(int source,String value){ if()field = value else ...}.  Dose it violate SRP?And how to do better?

Comment: @JainPing Please do not start to ask *more* things in comments. If you have enough content, then put up a *new* question (feel free to drop me a comment then) and delete the comments here. There is no point in asking *other* stuff in close-to unreadable comments!